# JSR-303 Bean Validation serialize result

Tags: spring, serialization, rpc, bean-validation

I am looking for a way to obtain a `JSR-303 Bean Validation` result server side, then get a serialised form with a map of the violated attribute and it's error message and send this to the client through RPC.

I am using `Spring` server side and `GWT RPC`.

The use of a Spring `BindingResult` isn't serialzable as is the `ConstraintViolation`. I would like to be able to serialise this BindingResult somehow.

Note: I am not using `Spring MVC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per specification *ConstraintViolation* is not serializable. In fact it would be hard to enforce it anyways, since the violation contains for example the validated object itself which might or might not be serializable. Hibernate Validators implementation of *ConstraintViolation* is serializable, but it only works if all your validated objects are serializable as well.

Personally I would not try to serialize _ConstraintViolation_s. Catch the validation exception server side and send some custom object back.

Comment: I made a custom serialization in the end. Thanks for background info